# Spring Integration - scatter-gather - dynamic value in releaseExpression

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am using scatter-gatter in a Spring Integration flow to call 3 services parallel:

```
                    .scatterGather(rlr -> rlr.applySequence(true)
                                             .recipientFlow(f1 -> f1
                                                    .channel(c -> c.executor(executorMLCalls))
                                                    .route(ifService1NeedsToBeCalled(), routeToService1OrBypassCall()))
                                             .recipientFlow(f2 -> f2
                                                    .channel(c -> c.executor(executorMLCalls))
                                                    .enrich(this::service2RequestEnricher)
                                                    .enrich(this::service2Enricher))
                                             .recipientFlow(f3 -> f3
                                                    .channel(c -> c.executor(executorMLCalls))
                                                    .enrich(this::service3RequestEnricher)
                                                    .enrich(this::service3Enricher)),
                                   agg -> agg.correlationStrategy(msg -> msg.getHeaders().get("corrMLCalls"))
                                             .releaseExpression("size() == 3"),
                                   sgs -> sgs.gatherTimeout(gatherTimeout)
                                             .requiresReply(true)
                    )
```

So the **service2** and **service3** have to be called always but calling the **service1** depends on conditions.
Due to this I cannot use the `size() == 3` release expression as sometimes it should be `size() == 2`.

How can I use dynamic value in the expression? Can I call a local method in the release expression?

Thank you!

Regards,
V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, such an expression is `BeanFactory`-aware and you can use a `@` syntax to reach any bean in your application context.

On the other hand there is a:

```
/**
 * @param releaseStrategy the release strategy.
 * @return the handler spec.
 * @see AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler#setReleaseStrategy(ReleaseStrategy)
 */
public S releaseStrategy(ReleaseStrategy releaseStrategy) {
```

Which may make any decission according your environment and `MessageGroup` as a releasing candidate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The `@` seems promising but how can I pass parameter to this method? Let's assume the method to be called is `isValid(Storage storage)` and the `Storage` is a simple bean where I store requests/responses and it is passed among SI components. How can pass this in the release expression? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, I would suggest to go the `ReleaseStrategy` impl in case of Java DSL. It is just a matter of lambda declaration! You can access any beans from there so

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I went with the `releaseStrategy` and it seems to work fine. However I bumped into another issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67836736/using-releasestrategy-but-flow-doesnt-continue