# Using releaseStrategy but flow doesn't continue

Tags: spring-integration

I am using the following main flow

```
    return flow -> flow.channel(REQUEST_INPUT)
            ...
            .enrich(this::calculationEnricher)
            .route(ifMLCallRequired(), routeToMLOrBypassCall())
            .enrich(this::subServiceRequestEnricher)
            ....
```

and the following subflow

```
Consumer<RouterSpec<Boolean, MethodInvokingRouter>> routeToMLOrBypassCall() {
    return rs -> rs.resolutionRequired(false)
            .subFlowMapping(true, sf -> sf
                .enrichHeaders(he -> he.headerExpression("corrMLCalls", "T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID().toString()"))
                .scatterGather(rlr -> rlr.applySequence(true)
                                         .recipientFlow(f1 -> f1
                                                .channel(c -> c.executor(executorMLCalls))
                                                .route(ifService1NeedsToBeCalled(), routeToService1OrBypassCall()))
                                         .recipientFlow(f2 -> f2
                                                .channel(c -> c.executor(executorMLCalls))
                                                .enrich(this::service2RequestEnricher)
                                                .enrich(this::service2Enricher))
                                         .recipientFlow(f3 -> f3
                                                .channel(c -> c.executor(executorMLCalls))
                                                .enrich(this::service3RequestEnricher)
                                                .enrich(this::service3Enricher)),
                               agg -> agg.correlationStrategy(msg -> msg.getHeaders().get("corrMLCalls"))
                                         .releaseExpression("size() == 2"),
                               sgs -> sgs.gatherTimeout(gatherTimeout)
                                         .requiresReply(true)
                )
                .handle(...
                )
                .defaultOutputToParentFlow();
}
```

The service2 and service3 are called always but the service1 depends on some condition. If the service 1 is not called (i.e. `size() == 2`) then I am experiencing a weird phenomena (well, at least it is strange to me...): after the `routeToMLOrBypassCall()` the `subServiceRequestEnricher` should be called but it is not. Only if I change the release condition to `size() == 3`. I presume it is related to the fact that I created 3 channels for each service and it expects something from each service?

The `routeToService1OrBypassCall()` looks like

```
Consumer<RouterSpec<Boolean, MethodInvokingRouter>> routeToService1OrBypassCall()() {
    return rs -> rs.resolutionRequired(false)
            .subFlowMapping(false, sf -> sf.enrich(this::service1RequestEnricher)
                                           .enrich(this::service1Enricher)
            )
            .defaultOutputToParentFlow();
}
```

Should I add something to the **true** branch too...?

I appreciate any help! Thank you!

Regards, V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is too complicated and it is hard to understand what is going on with such a sub-flows configuration.

Probably you need to think about replacing your router logic to the simple `.filter()`. That one can produce a reply on `true` and won't do anything on `false`.

The router has its drawback that it doesn't produce to the reply channel as is and it just ends up in the sub-flow it routes to.

Comment: Hi, sorry about the late reply! I am very sorry, it was my bad, I made some funky stuff in my code... The release strategy works fine!